# Integration by substitution to take out square root

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Find $$\int (x+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx .$$

In order to not bother with the square root I thought of doing this:

$let$ $ x^2+1=(x+t)^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=\frac{1-t^2}{2t}$ $\Rightarrow x-t=\frac{1+t^2}{2t}$ $(1)$

$\Rightarrow$ $t=\sqrt{x^2+1}-x$ $(2)$

And

$dx=-\frac{t^2+1}{2t^2}dt $ $(3)$

and also $x+1=-\frac{t^2-2t-1}{2t}$ $(4)$

Then

$(1),(3),(4)\Rightarrow$$\int (x+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=$ $\int\frac{t^2-2t-1}{2t} \frac{1-t^2}{2t} \frac{t^2+1}{2t}dt=$

$\frac{1}{8} \int \frac{-t^6+2t^5+t^4+t^2-2t-1}{t^3}dt=$

$\frac{1}{8} [-\int t^3 dt+2\int t^2 dt+\int t dt +\int \frac{1}{t} dt-2 \int \frac{1}{t^2} dt- \int \frac{1}{t^3}dt]=$

$\frac{1}{8}[-\frac{t^4}{4}+2\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^2}{2}+lnt+\frac{2}{t}-\frac{1}{2t^2}]$

We do the substitution from $(2)$ and we get the result

You think that's correct?

Comment: To check, take the derivative of your solution.

Comment: I believe an easier alternative is to proceed as follows:$$\int x\sqrt{x^2+1}~dx+\int\sqrt{x^2+1}~dx=\frac{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}3+\frac x2\sqrt{x^2+1}+\frac12\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+C
$$whereby the first integral is solved through the substitution $x^2+1=t$ and the second one is an integral of the standard form $\displaystyle\int\sqrt{x^2+a^2}~dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the rationalizing substitution, I think you made a few errors. It should be
$$\int (x+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx=\int\frac{t^2-2t-1}{2t}\cdot \frac{t^2+1}{2t}\cdot \frac{t^2+1}{2t^2}dt.$$

Alternative approach by using [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Definitions).

Let $x=\sinh(t)$ then $\cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)=1$ and
$$\begin{align*}\int (x+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx &=\int (\sinh(t)+1)\sqrt{\sinh^2(t)+1}\,\cosh(t) dt \\
&=\int (\sinh(t)+1)\cosh^2(t) dt\\
&=\frac{\cosh^3(t)}{3}+ \frac{\cosh(t)\sinh(t)}{2}+\frac{t}{2}+c\\
&=\frac{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{x(x^2+1)^{1/2}}{2}+\frac{\text{arcsinh}(x)}{2}+c
\end{align*}.$$

Comment: Yep you are right I messed up with the substitution. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, if you are new here please take a few moments for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Before trying the substitution, it is worth to simplify the integrand, by observing that

$$(x^2+1)'=2x$$ so that

$$\int(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac13(x^2+1)^{3/2}+\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx.$$

For the last integral, substitution with $x=\sinh t$ will allow to get rid of the square root. By parts intégration also works:

$$I:=\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx=x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$

and

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\int\frac{x^2+1-1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=I-\text{arshinh } x,$$ from which you draw $I$.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding hyperbolic functions, I believe you can do a trigonometric substitution: consider a right triangle with angle $\theta$ for which the opposite side is $x$, the adjacent side is $1$, and (thus) the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$.

Then $x = \tan{\theta}$, so $dx = \sec^2{\theta}d\theta$; note that $\sec{\theta} = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ and your integral becomes:

$$\int(x+1)\sqrt{x^2 + 1}dx = \int(\tan{\theta} + 1)\sec^3{\theta} d\theta = \int\tan{\theta}\sec^3{\theta} + \sec^3{\theta} d \theta$$

The first part of the integrand is not difficult, since $u = \sec{\theta}$ yields $du = \sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}d\theta$, whereby

$$\int \tan\theta \sec^3\theta d\theta = \int u^2 du$$

and finding the antiderivative of secant cubed is now the only task that remains. If you have seen this before ([**example link**](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Secant-cubed_function#First_antiderivative)) then you have reduced the problem to something familiar. If not, then you can use the already provided answer(s) for an alternative derivation of this function's antiderivative!